# Collections.sort on List<Interface> when implementer classes have their own compareTo

Tags: java, sorting, collections, polymorphism

I've interface `MyInterface` and two classes ( `Summary`, `Detail`) are implementing this, and overriding `compareTo`.
A third class `DetailMe` is extending `Detail`

Another class (`MyApi`) is using `List<MyInterface>` , and complaining for `Collections.sort` , what am i doing wrong ?

```
public class Summmary implements MyInterface, Comparable<Summary> {

   private Detail detail;

   public Summary(Detail detail) {
      this.detail = detail;
   }
    // properties

    // methods

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Summary o) {

        // Do work
    }
}
```

==

```
public class Detail implements MyInterface, Comparable<Detail> {

    // properties

    // methods

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Detail o) {

        // Do Detail work
    }
}
```

==

```
public class DetailMe extends Detail {
 // Do work
}
```

==

```
public class MyApi {

    private List<MyInterface> myList;

    public MyApi(List<MyInterface> myList) {
        this.myList = myList
        Collections.sort(this.myList); // COMPLIATION ERROR

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried having your `MyInterface` extend `Comparable<MyInterface>`.  That will force you to implement `compareTo(MyInterface other)` in your classes that implement `MyInterface`.  I think that should then allow you to call `Collections.sort()` on a `List<MyInterface>`

Comment: That was it :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure (in a way the compiler knows of) that the list only contains one type of object, because your objects can't compare with each other.

So, your list must be either a `List<Summmary>` or a `List<Detail>`.

That is, unless you define the ordering of mixed elements, but then both classes would have to implement `public int compareTo(MyInterface o)`.

Comment: Still not work. I also edited my question, as classes Detail & Summary were implementing Comparable.

Comment: I cannot have List<Summary> or List<Detail> as i want to keep it generic.

Comment: So i tried public int compareTo(MyInterface o) in both Summary and Detail after using Comparable<MyInterface> in class signature, but it still complained with same error.

Comment: @NoviceUser That's because `MyInterface` must extend `Comparable<MyInterface>` for a `List<MyInterface>` to be sortable by it's natural ordering.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks !